# Is marquee tag still implemented in modern browsers?

Tags: html, cross-browser

I know that `<marquee>` tag is deprecated, but I have to use it for a simple presentation. And it's important to me that it will work on every laptop in the room.
I know it works on modern chrome (It still works for v44)

Are there any browsers that DON'T implement marquee behaviour?

/Edit I wanted to check it on http://caniuse.com/. But there is no info about it

Comment: Better use CSS instead.

Comment: Why downvoted? Don't You get the question? I just want to make sure that marquee works everywhere

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it might be because the question is a bit too broad. I could download the source code of Firefox or Chromium, remove the marquee code, compile it, and distribute it. That would be a modern browser with no marquee support.

Comment: I mean regular browser releases. Opera, Safari, Firefox, Chromium.
Stuff people ussually use.

Comment: The marquee element was never part of any HTML standard. I don't recall why it's mentioned here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#obsolete but, even then, it's listed as "obsolete".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<marquee>` tag is still supported by IE (8-11), Edge, Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.

**Note**

That being said, it is non-standard, and generally considered bad practice, especially given that you can do something very similar in CSS.

Comment: You can't deprecate something that was never part of any HTML standard.

Comment: @Rob fair, bad terminology on my part. What would you say instead, "non-standard"?

Comment: Your very first sentence is correct. I would just reword your Note to say it was non-standard or never a part of the HTML standard.

Comment: Done. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Is there any *short* css code to imitate marquee behavior?

Comment: There used to be `-webkit-marquee`, but it's since been abandoned by W3C ( http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-marquee/ ). I would recommend using `white-space: nowrap`, custom overflow, and a basic CSS animation for scrolling.